# How much does it cost to service a MacBook Pro battery?

Tags: battery

I have a mid 2009 MacBook Pro and I just got a message saying that I should service my battery.

I tried to reset SMC and NVRAM but the problem persists and I fear I'll have my battery replaced. How much is Apple going to charge me?

My Mac is out of warranty and I see that the battery capacity is less than 80% than it was originally but apart from that it is working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Replacing the Battery in your MacBook Pro](http://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro/service/battery/) for pricing information in various countries. In your case (Italy) it's 130 or 180€ depending on screen size.